# My object is not affected by light

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, light

In viewport shading, I have screen lights and world view on. I turn down the color of my world from grey to black. Everything else in my scene is affected by the dim light, but not my character's clothes.
I got the material from poliigon, so I am not too familiar with the setup.
I want the clothes to have shadows and be affected by the light. I am guessing it's a node-setup issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]